# Combine results from multiple views and add identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a view that selects and joins data from several tables. 
I have this same view in multiple databases on different servers. (it's part of the same application installed on various servers)

What I'm trying to do is use the **'Export Data'** wizard to create an **`SSIS package`** that copies the data from these views to a single data warehouse database.

However, since I can't guarantee that there won't be identical rows in the the views, I want to add an ID column in the data warehouse db. But I can't seem to get it to work. 
Usually when you want to add an autoincrement `ID`, one simply inserts `'NULL'` into that column. So I've added a `'NULL'` value to the select of the view. And I've added an `ID column` to the destination table, with Identity and auto-increment on.

However, when I run the Export Data wizard, it gives an error

> 'The value violated the integrity constraints for the column.'

Does anyone have an idea how to combine data from different views on different db servers and add a unique identifier in the destination table?

Cheers, CJ

Comment: You cannot insert null into an ID column, try excluding the column from the insert statement. It should auto-populate with the increment properly.

Comment: You are absolutely right. So simple. How silly of me. Shame I can't accept your comment as the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert NULL into the Primary Key. Just don't insert anything into the ID column if you have it as auto incremented. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
(
ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
test varchar(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO test_table(test )
VALUES ('some value');
```

And ID will be set to 1 for this record.